# Modifying XML using XSL, ignoring an element

Tags: xslt

I've got the following XML:

```
<BNF_DETAILS xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bnf_v1_0.xsd" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <!-- Generated by NHSBSA PPD -->
        <VMPS>
            <VMP>
                <VPID>40689311000001106</VPID>
                <BNF>08010100</BNF>
                <ATC>L01EL03</ATC>
                <DDD>320</DDD>
                <DDD_UOMCD>258684004</DDD_UOMCD>
            </VMP>
            <VMP>
              ...
            </VMP>
        </VMPS>
        
        <AMPS />
    </BNF_DETAILS>
```

What I'm after is an .xsl file which will convert this to the following (removing the BNF element).

```
<VMP>
    <VPID>40689311000001106</VPID>
    <ATC>L01EL03</ATC>
    <DDD>320</DDD>
    <DDD_UOMCD>258684004</DDD_UOMCD>
</VMP>
<VMP>
    ...
</VMP>
```

Can someone help please. I've been looking into XSL for the past couple of hours and I'm still stuck.

Comment: Well, what have you tried, how did it fail? Are you able to use XSLT 2 or 3 with `xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"` support?

Comment: Removing the root node will generate an invalid XML file. Probably not what you intend to do.